# Exporting data from Google Cloud Storage to Amazon S3 using Airflow

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, airflow

Is it possible to use Airflow to export data from Google Cloud Storage to Amazon S3?

Both GCS and S3 have hooks but not sure how exactly to enable the export of data directly between the buckets without copying the data locally on airflow server.